# Television repair - connectors and standards for display panel and controller boards

Tags: repair, video, standard, tv, tuner

All my experience comes from 2 flat TVs, so my knowledge is quite reduced and questions have to be quite broad.

Questions:

Are there standards or common practices from manufactures about connections on display panels? So, Is there a chance of connecting a TV flat panel with boards from other TVs?

How commonly do manufacturers separate boards by functions? I assume that power supply has a specific board always but what about input/output, audio/video controller, internet?

If it were common, is there common boards to exchange boards among different models or brands?

Are there generic/compatible internal boards offering TV/HbbTV functions for old or broken TVs?
Options to upgrade a HbbTV v1.x to v2.x

Note that I am not asking for USB or other external solutions with pay-tv, Youtube, use Android apps or browse the internet, I know that they exist but is not the answer to any question.
Furthermore, i assume that a external device with internet will not offer HbbTV (HybridTV) as it requires a tuner to broadcasted signal(red? blue? color button on the remote)

Comment: A real example. Years ago I bought a smartTV, probably based in linux (browser, netflix and few more) (internally it is manufactured by Vestel).The TV never received a single FW update, so after few years most "internet" functions stopped working, including access to Hybrid Television or data from broadcast channels, (in europe HbbTV).
However, the LCD panel works perfectly, so the only reason to consider a replacements is the lack of compatibility with internet functions.

Comment: What makes you think manufacturers build TVs so that they can be easily repaired? The ridiculous low pricing on home electronics means they have absolutely zero margins. If I buy a stack of wooden planks spat out from a lumber mill, then it costs more than a TV with 1000+ components in it. As long as consumers think that pricing makes sense, no quality TV will ever get produced.

Comment: @Lundin it is not about design or support for repair from manufacturers; (though it should be inforced by law) .Most of brands just buy and join boards and parts from 3rd parties, and being parts common to many brands and models, having information replacing/upgrading parts should be  feasible

Comment: I have no idea how it is done personally. But buying 3rd party modules sounds expensive and not something to even consider for extreme low-price products like TV. As I see it, only two business models are possible: either put it all on a single board where you mix power (likely through-hole) components with RF, or you separate power and RF into two separate boards. Splitting it up further would mean a lot of extra costs. In case they'd buy 3rd party modules, those are likely soldered in place on some main RF board and never meant to be replaced.

Comment: Enforcing standardization, repair-ability, environment-friendly design etc etc will mean that the price would go up to reasonable levels of approximately the double of what a TV costs today. But the problem here is that the consumers aren't reasonable, so they will never accept that. Therefore laws will only serve to separate the serious vendors from "Alibaba" vendors and the Alibaba TV would then massively cut into the profits of vendors producing legal TVs.